# Example of sort/filter using JavascriptMVC and thoughts/comments about JavascriptMVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks

Here goes my first post @ Stack Overflow :)
I have been a long time user and always found my answer here but I dont see much about javascriptMVC here ...

Recently I started working on it and sadly not getting much documentation/examples around this framework.

Can anyone help me with example or how-to of doing simple sort/filter using this framework?
Official API doc as given below doesn't explain much.

http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.Model.List.prototype.sort

Also, even though it looks like strong contender to backbone.js and others, it seems like lately there havent been much talks/attention about it in javascript community.

It would be great, if anyone share comments,thoughts about the javascriptMVC from their experience and current trends.

Other frameworks we are trying are backbone.js and ember.js
So we are comparing javascriptMVC with other two

Best,
Sumit

Comment: Frameworks completely depends on your needs and on your applications. To optimum solution is _always_ a custom framework tailored to the application (though that's not time optimum)

Comment: The first part of your question is appropriate here, but the question about the future of the framework probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com or maybe http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

To sort a list:

```
list.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.Value > b.Value) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.Value < b.Value) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

To filter a list:

```
var filteredList = list.grep(function (item, i) {
    return a.Value > 10;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rynos and gilly3 ... I just wanted to know thoughts about this framework from the stackoverflow community. I have corrected my question so its more appropriate @gilly3, it seems like this will just update the list object, but what we need to do to view the sorted result in our view ?

Comment: This looks right.  Traditionally, sort functions get 2 arguments, `a, b`, and simply need to return `1` if `a` is bigger, `-1` if `b` is bigger or `0` if they are equal.  The sort method uses those values to then order the resulting array accordingly.